# cleverer boundary detection schemes-ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
if((self.Latitude > -6 && self.Latitude < 55) && (self.Longitude >37 && self.Longitude <  180))
{
    [continent addObject:@"Asia"];

}
```

I am trying to detect continents based on coordinates. The coordinates in the if condition form a square boundary around the continent. How do we specify cleverer boundaries so that coordinates are limited to exact boundary of Asia not including any parts of Europe.

Answer (score 2):

Build a `CGPath` that outlines the continent, then use `CGPathContainsPoint` to see if the point is on the continent.

You'll need to find a source for the continental outline data. Maybe you can use the [OpenStreetMap land outlines](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/land-polygons).

Comment: Should I extract points from the .shp file and pass it to CGPath to draw the outline of the continents?

Comment: You should extract points to construct a path for coordinate testing, since that is what you wanted to do in your original question. If you also want to use the path for drawing, I don't mind.

Comment: thank you for your reference. It would be great if you could provide reference on how to extract contents of shape file into an array of points